# What moves can hit me when using fly?

Tags: pokemon-series

It was my understanding, and from past experience, that the move "Swift" was the only move that could hit you when using "Fly". Kind of like Earthquake being able to hit me when using Dig. But I was recently playing Heart Gold and I was taken out with Thunder when I was flying.

So what all moves can hit you when using Fly? And did the types of moves that can hit you change throughout the different generations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [the moves that can hit you](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Fly) have changed over time:

- In Generation I, [Bide](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Bide_(move)), [Swift](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Swift_(move)) and [Transform](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Transform_(move)) were all able to connect (however, starting with Pokémon Stadium, Bide lost this ability again).
- Generation II replaces this list with [Gust](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Gust_(move)), [Thunder](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Thunder_(move)), [Twister](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Twister_(move)) and [Whirlwind](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Whirlwind_(move)). Additionally, Gust and Twister do *double damage* against a flying opponent, and *any* move can hit if [Lock-On](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Lock-On_(move)) or [Mind Reader](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mind_Reader_(move)) was used the previous turn.
- Generation III adds [Sky Uppercut](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sky_Uppercut_(move)) to the list of unavoidable moves.
- Generation IV lets all Pokémon with the [No Guard](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/No_Guard_(ability)) ability hit a flying Pokémon with any move.

Presumably, the Generation I list was actually a bug which caused the "semi-invulnerable" check to get skipped (with Bide getting fixed for Stadium); the list used for Generation II and on were selected because it makes sense that these moves can still hit while the opponent is flying.

Comment: Couldn't Blizzard hit Fly back in the day? I'm just going off of the top of my head

Comment: @Samjus: I certainly don't recall that ever happening in any of the generations, but again, the mechanics have changed over time, so the answer might depend on when "back in the day" was. It certainly wouldn't have been the case in Generation I, at least; Blizzard was just an ordinary move and had no reason to trigger the bug which allowed Swift to hit.

Comment: Looks like i'm going to have to pull out the bag of nostalgia and play some POKEMON

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure, but I think smack down makes you fly down in gen. 6 I don't know anything about the other generations.

Comment: Welcome to ArQAde! We may do things a little differently here than you may be used to. We are not a forum, and typically like our answers to contain factual information. If you are unsure, then test it out, possibly do a little research, and get back to us with the results. It may be beneficial to (re)read our [About Page](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and our [Help Center](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) (specifically the "[How do I write a good answer?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)" article).